# Playwright error: browserType.launch: Browser has been closed

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, playwright

This is how my pipeline is setup:

`stages:

- test
  tests:
  stage: test
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.34.1-focal
  script:

  - apt-get install nodejs
  - npm i
  - npx playwright test`

From the CI logs, I get this error message: browserType.launch: Browser has been closed

I checked online that it was mention that I can run it in headless mode but that also not worked.